Grid of same-height items with conditional "banner" outside of item without setting height explicitly
I'm trying to achieve following grid:

HTML structure is following:


.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  
}

.container > article {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.item-layout {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.banner {
  background: red;
}
<div class="container">
    <article>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <span class="banner">Banner</span>
            <div class="item-layout">
                <header>header</header>
                <div class="body">content to be expanded</div>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item-layout">
                <header>header</header>
                <div class="body">content to be expanded</div>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item-layout">
                <header>header</header>
                <div class="body">content to be expanded and more content, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="banner">Banner</span>
            <div class="item-layout">
                <header>header</header>
                <div class="body">content to be expanded</div>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item-layout">
                <header>header</header>
                <div class="body">content to be expanded</div>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>



Height of items in the row should be the same with conditional banner sticking outside the item. Items might have different content, so I can't set height explicitly. Instead I want to use flex-grow to "body" of item to expand it if necessary.
Using grid for "container" and flex, flex-direction: column and justify-content: flex-end for "wrapper" I was able to do it, but it fails if there is not enough content in item in the row, items will be uneven.
To overcome this, I used flex-grow to "body" and "item-layout". Now items are even, but item with "banner" are aligned to other items without banner.
Any idea on how to do this without explicitly setting height and min-height?

That sounds like a local network issue. Stack's image service is working fine.

@TylerH thanks, I'm fine if it's working for everyone else. I removed my previous comment

If you can restructure the HTML to remove the somewhat extraneous article and .item-layout wrapping elements, you can manage this with display: grid and subgrid.


.header {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  gap: .25em;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-row: span 4;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.wrapper * {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}

header {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="header">Banner</span>
    <header>header</header>
    <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed culpa fugit praesentium. Excepturi eos fuga ex explicabo porro saepe dolor commodi molestias illum, at voluptatum.</div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="header">Banner</span>
    <header>header</header>
    <div class="body">content to be expanded</div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <header>header</header>
    <div class="body">content to be expanded</div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="header">Banner</span>

    <header>header</header>
    <div class="body">content to be expanded</div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <header>header</header>
    <div class="body">content to be expanded</div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>



Note: If the HTML cannot be altered this will still be possible if we apply display: contents to the extra wrapping elements - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/poXbOQZ?editors=1100
